# How can a user who forget password reset the password

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Users can sign in using either email/password or username/password. For username, the code creates a non-functioning email e.g username@xxx.com. email verification is set to false. A user may forget password so a help is provided using user questions/answers stored in firestore database collections. If the answers are correct, user can provide a new password which will be updated in firebase authentication. And this is my challenge, how to update user password in firebase authentication.

Below is my code:

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
getAuth()
    .updateUser(userId, {
        email: enteredUsername.trim().toLowerCase(),
        emailVerified: false,
        password: enteredNewPassword.trim(),
        disabled: false,
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
        console.log('Successfully updated user', userRecord.toJSON());
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error updating user:', error);
    });
```

Above gives error message:

> TypeError: (0, _auth.getAuth)().updateUser is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
> How do I correct this error

Now I have a config.js file (though I think this may not be useful for this purpose:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth} from "firebase/auth";//This is for dev
import { collection, initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";//This is for production
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "value",
  authDomain: "value",
  projectId: "value",
  storageBucket: "value",
  messagingSenderId: "value",
  appId: "value"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
export const db = initializeFirestore(app, { experimentalForceLongPolling: true });// This is for production
export const userRef = collection(db, 'Users');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the reference documentation for the [React Native Firebase `auth` object](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth), it doesn't have any method called `updateUser` - so that'd explain the error you get. You'll have to stick to the methods that are provided there in order for the code to compile (and work).

Valid methods on the [`User` object](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/user) are [`updateProfile`](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/updateprofile), [`updateEmail`](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/user#updateEmail), [`updatePassword`](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth/user#updatePassword), etc.

---

There is no way to securely reset the password in the way you described with just client-side code, as anyone can make calls to the Firebase Authentication API without the security questions that you implemented. If you want to allow this use-case, you will have to perform the validation of the security questions server-side and then from there [update the user through the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user). The Node.js Admin SDK **does** have an `updateUser` method, but can only be used in secure environments (such as your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run), but not from a React Native app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
Yes user cannot have direct access to the back end because I validate answers to the security questions. 
The code above is a much shorter version of the main code. 
Now I install firebase using npm i firebase and not from react-native. 
So do I have to run npm i react-native/firebase in addition to what I have now? 
Or delete existing firebase dependencies and replace with react-native/firebase

Comment: Sorry, but writign a step-by-step guide on how to build this use-case is beyond what we can reasonably do on Stack Overflow. --- Is it clear from my answer why your current code doesn't work? You're trying to call methods that don't exist in the SDK you use. --- Then: you can't use the Firebase Admin SDK in your React Native app. You will need to run this code in a trusted environment, like your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run. If you're having trouble installing/using the Admin SDK, I recommend opening a new question for that.